# What's the equivalent of `gcloud beta run deploy --image [image] --allow-unauthenticated` in REST?

Tags: google-cloud-run

What's the equivalent of `gcloud beta run deploy --image [image] --allow-unauthenticated` in REST?

Is it just the https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha1/namespaces.services/create ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer. However, when I want the same information I turn on gcloud debugging and review the HTTP calls made from gcloud.

Comment: @JohnHanley how do I enable debugging? I tried with --verbosity=debug but with no success... Does debug shows the params too? Thanks.

Comment: Found it! It's --log-http

Comment: gcloud --log-http --verbosity=debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That command is two REST calls made in quick succession. First, a call to [services.create](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha1/namespaces.services/create) followed by a call to [services.setIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha1/projects.locations.services/setIamPolicy) to grant "roles/run.invoker" to "allUsers" which allows unauthenticated use.